# Map as a published property of custom element

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Dartium gave me this error when I load my app (dart version, not compiled js) into browser:

```
Uncaught Error: Error evaluating expression 'model["mode"]': EvalException: Can't assign to null: model
```

I can see the error is caused by some code like this:

```dart
<polymer-element name="outer-element">
  <!-- some codes here -->

  <inner-element mode="model['mode']"></inner-element>

</polymer-element>
```

Where the `model` is a `Map`, `model['mode']` is `String`, and the `mode` is declared via `@published String mode` on `<inner-element>`. Also, `model` is declared on `<outer-element>` via `@published Map model` so I can pass some map to `<outer-element>` in another custom element using `<outer-element model="{{some map}}">`.

This error doesn't make the app crash, actually, it has no effect as far as I can see, but it's really annoying to see it. (I have this error since the beginning of my development!)

I go through the data flow, but cannot find the problem.

Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks.

Version:
dart 1.4.2
polymer 0.10.1+1
polymer_expressions 0.10.0
dartium-win-full-stable-36647.0

If it helps, here is the stack trace:

```
Uncaught Error: Error evaluating expression 'model["mode"]': EvalException: Can't assign to null: model
Stack Trace: 
#0      assign (package:polymer_expressions/eval.dart:137:18)
#1      _Binding.value= (package:polymer_expressions/polymer_expressions.dart:142:28)
#2      HtmlElement&Polymer.bindProperty (package:polymer/src/instance.dart:675:16)
#3      HtmlElement&Polymer.bind (package:polymer/src/instance.dart:447:34)
#4      _processBindings (package:template_binding/src/template_iterator.dart:186:38)
#5      _cloneAndBindInstance (package:template_binding/src/instance_binding_map.dart:71:19)
#6      _cloneAndBindInstance (package:template_binding/src/instance_binding_map.dart:60:26)
#7      _cloneAndBindInstance (package:template_binding/src/instance_binding_map.dart:60:26)
#8      TemplateBindExtension.createInstance (package:template_binding/src/template.dart:87:40)
#9      HtmlElement&Polymer.instanceTemplate (package:polymer/src/instance.dart:430:44)
#10     HtmlElement&Polymer.shadowFromTemplate (package:polymer/src/instance.dart:288:31)
#11     HtmlElement&Polymer.parseDeclaration (package:polymer/src/instance.dart:228:34)
#12     HtmlElement&Polymer.parseDeclarations (package:polymer/src/instance.dart:215:23)
#13     HtmlElement&Polymer.prepareElement (package:polymer/src/instance.dart:190:22)
#14     HtmlElement&Polymer.bind (package:polymer/src/instance.dart:437:42)
#15     _processBindings (package:template_binding/src/template_iterator.dart:186:38)
#16     _cloneAndBindInstance (package:template_binding/src/instance_binding_map.dart:71:19)
#17     TemplateBindExtension.createInstance (package:template_binding/src/template.dart:87:40)
#18     _TemplateIterator._handleSplices (package:template_binding/src/template_iterator.dart:449:53)
#19     _TemplateIterator._valueChanged (package:template_binding/src/template_iterator.dart:330:19)
#20     _TemplateIterator._updateIteratedValue (package:template_binding/src/template_iterator.dart:303:18)
#21     _TemplateIterator._updateDependencies (package:template_binding/src/template_iterator.dart:287:25)
#22     TemplateBindExtension._processBindingDirectives (package:template_binding/src/template.dart:50:34)
#23     _processBindings (package:template_binding/src/template_iterator.dart:197:51)
#24     _cloneAndBindInstance (package:template_binding/src/instance_binding_map.dart:71:19)
#25     _cloneAndBindInstance (package:template_binding/src/instance_binding_map.dart:60:26)
#26     _cloneAndBindInstance (package:template_binding/src/instance_binding_map.dart:60:26)
#27     TemplateBindExtension.createInstance (package:template_binding/src/template.dart:87:40)
#28     _TemplateIterator._handleSplices (package:template_binding/src/template_iterator.dart:449:53)
#29     _TemplateIterator._valueChanged (package:template_binding/src/template_iterator.dart:330:19)
#30     _updateIteratedValue (package:template_binding/src/template_iterator.dart:303:18)
#31     _check (package:polymer_expressions/polymer_expressions.dart:131:16)
#32     dirtyCheckZoneSpec.wrapUnaryCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:observe/src/dirty_check.dart:120:15)
#33     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:730)
#34     _ZoneDelegate.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:462)
#35     _CustomizedZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:667)
#36     _BaseZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:582)
#37     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:333)
#38     _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:585)
#39     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:701)
#40     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:661)
#41     dirtyCheckZoneSpec.wrapCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:observe/src/dirty_check.dart:111:15)
#42     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:719)
#43     _ZoneDelegate.run (dart:async/zone.dart:453)
#44     _CustomizedZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:663)
#45     _BaseZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:574)
#46     _BaseZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:599)
#47     dirtyCheckZoneSpec.wrapCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:observe/src/dirty_check.dart:111:15)
#48     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:723)
#49     _ZoneDelegate.run (dart:async/zone.dart:453)
#50     _CustomizedZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:663)
#51     _BaseZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:574)
#52     _BaseZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:599)
#53     _asyncRunCallbackLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:23)
#54     _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:32)
#55     _handleMutation (file:///E:/b/build/slave/dartium-win-full-stable/build/src/dart/tools/dom/src/native_DOMImplementation.dart:588)
```

Comment: What Polymer version are you using? When (with what Polymer version) did you start developing this Polymer app?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Just edited the question to add the version. I started the development several months ago, this error only appears in the compiled version then, (my guess is that the dart vm didn't show the error then, but it happened). You answered my several questions before, thanks :-)

Comment: When and how do you initialize `model` in `<outer-element>`?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it has to do with:
[Binding initialization when model is null](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/polymer-dev/assign%2420to%2420null/polymer-dev/hKXeBB8gJuo/8B7TaO5KqzQJ)

see also the comment here:
[Polymer template repeat has weird side effect](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17981#c8)

The binding initialization can lead to situations where Polymer assigns to null or to non-assignable expressions. Previously they tried to suppress this errors but have seen situations where this is actually a bug and the developer should be notified about it, so they changed the behavior that errors are not suppressed but printed.

They try to figure out a way to improve this experience but seems not too easy.

This is just how I interpret some posts I read, I don't have any additional infos.